# Is there any way/any python function to calculate the condition number of the roots of a polynomial directly?

Tags: linear-algebra, python, polynomials, condition-number

I know that NumPy has `linalg.cond(A)` to find the condition number of a matrix A. But, if I want to find the condition numbers of the roots of a large polynomial with respect to a small perturbation (something like Wilkinson's polynomial), is there a function that can give me the condition numbers of the roots directly?

I was also thinking along the lines of expressing the polynomial above in the form of a diagonal matrix itself, so that the diagonal entries are then the eigenvalues anyway and they form this polynomial when the determinant is taken, but 1. I'm not sure if that's correct, and 2. I still don't know how I'll get the condition numbers of each root from that since the condition number calculated by `cond(A)` is for a matrix specifically?

I've also searched extensively on Google and StackOverflow/math.SE but I can't seem to find anything relevant that isn't completely mathematical. Can anyone help out?

Comment: I wonder if something involving the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) will be helpful?

Comment: Ohhh I didn't know this was a thing, but this looks interesting, I'll see if this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The condition number of a root $r$ of a polynomial $p$ is

$$
\kappa := \frac{\left\| p \right\|}{|rp'(r)|}
$$

There is some arbitrariness in the choice of norm which affects the definition of the condition number. [This](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ejan/mcs471/conditioning.pdf) suggests taking the largest coefficient of the polynomial.

[Corless](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-8453-0) considers perturbations of the coefficients of the polynomial under the rounding model of floating point arithmetic. This results in the condition number

$$
\kappa = \frac{1}{|rp'(r)|} \sum_{i} |c_{i}r^i|
$$

These are all straightforward to compute, in Python or any language for that matter.

Note: After computing a root $\tilde{r}$, I prefer to use the residual $|p(\tilde{r})|$ rather than the condition number to evaluate the quality of the solve. To wit, I know the in the best case, I have $\tilde{r} = r(1+\epsilon)$, so then I Taylor expand to get $|p(\tilde{r})| \approx \epsilon |rp'(r)|$. If $|p(\tilde{r})| \gg \epsilon |\tilde{r}p'(\tilde{r})|$, then I know something is wrong.

Update: Since posting this, I have found another definition of the rootfinding condition number in the infinity norm, given by [Higham](https://nhigham.com/2020/03/19/what-is-a-condition-number/). Given $p(z) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i z^{i}$ and a simple root $r$, the condition number is

$$
\kappa_{\infty}(p, r) := \frac{\left\| \mathbf{c}\right\|_{\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n} |r|^{i}}{|r p'(r)|}
$$

This is can be generated by an easy inequality and is strictly larger than the condition number defined by Corless.

Comment: Isn't this the inverse of the condition number?

Comment: It's the inverse of the condition number of evaluation.

Comment: Ahh I see, so I'd have to do it manually regardless. Thank you for this! I'll check and see what I can do then! Also, is there a difference between getting the condition number vs. getting the inverse of a condition number? I don't think I've heard of the second thing before, so I'm slightly confused.

Comment: The condition number of rootfinding is what is specified above. Imagine it as follows: If the function is very steep ($|f'(x)| \gg 1$) then small changes in $x$ lead to large errors in evaluation of the function. But this means that rootfinding is well-conditioned, as a large slope makes it *easy* to recover the root accurately.

Comment: I don't understand the first formula. What is $\|p\|$? Is it a norm of the *polynomial*, or is it meant to be something like $|p(r)|$ (which would make no sense since $p(r)=0$)?

Comment: You have to choose a norm which defines the relevant scale. This is why I suggest using the residual instead.

Comment: A good reference is Corless, A Graduate Introduction to Numerical Methods, Section 3.2.1. In that works, he considers perturbations of the coefficients of the polynomial, which results in $\tilde{p}(\tilde{r}) \approx \epsilon r p'(r) + \delta p(r)$ where $p$ is the polynomial with exact coefficients, and $\delta p$ is the perturbation of the polynomial under the assumption that each coefficient is rounded according to the floating point model.

Comment: @user14717 ohhh this book looks good, and definitely very detailed. I'm mostly following the Trefethan & Bau book on Numerical LA, and I was having some difficulty understanding some things, so I'll definitely take a look at this. Also, thank you for your answer!